# Accessing certain values in nested JSON response from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I am currently getting data from an external API and I am able to display some data. however I want to be able to access certain data but not sure how to get all of it. Here is a snippet of the JSON response that I get from the API.

```
hits":[10 items
  0:{3 items
  "recipe":{...}18 items
  "bookmarked":false
  "bought":false
  }
    1:{3 items
    "recipe":{18 items
    "uri":"http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_8275bb28647abcedef0baaf2dcf34f8b"
    "label":"Chicken Paprikash"
    "image":"https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e12/e12b8c5581226d7639168f41d126f2ff.jpg"
    "source":"No Recipes"
    "url":"http://norecipes.com/recipe/chicken-paprikash/"
    "shareAs":"http://www.edamam.com/recipe/chicken-paprikash-8275bb28647abcedef0baaf2dcf34f8b/chicken"
    "yield":4
    "dietLabels":[...]1 item
    "healthLabels":[...]3 items
    "cautions":[...]2 items
    "ingredientLines":[...]11 items
    "ingredients":[12 items
       0:{2 items
       "text":"640 grams chicken - drumsticks and thighs ( 3 whole chicken legs cut apart)"
       "weight":640
       }
       1:{2 items
      "text":"640 grams chicken - drumsticks and thighs ( 3 whole chicken legs cut apart)"
      "weight":640
      }
      2:{2 items
      "text":"1/2 teaspoon salt"
      "weight":3
      }
```

I want to access "text" in all of the "ingredients" arrays. right now to get data to display I am doing:

```
<% @recipe.each do |r| %>
<img src=<%= r["recipe"]["image"] %> class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h8 class ="title", style = "text-align: center;"><%= r["recipe"]["label"] %></h8>
    <h8><%= r["recipe"]["dietLabels"] %></h8>
    </br>
    <ul>
    <li><h8 class="card-title"><h8><%= r["recipe"]["ingredients"][0]["text"] %></h8></li>

    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Which works but as you can see I am only getting the text in each ingredient at indices 0. Is there a way for me to get all the text as in the JSON response there are many meals and all have different amount of ingredients so It will not work to type out each indices separately. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please do _not_ supply a "snippet" of JSON. JSON is an object in a serialized form, so without the full stream we're left with an impartial object which we're then forced to change, inducing some wobble into our answers. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your views

```
<% @ingredients = r["recipe"]["ingredients"] %>
<ul>
  <% @ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <li><h8 class="card-title"><%= ingredient['text'] %><h8></h8></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I get this error when i try this `undefined local variable or method r'for #<RecipieController:0x000000000bd4b2e0>`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: yeah that worked thank you !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If it has helped you do mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @Gautam: Don't push for being the selected answer. See "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)"
"[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)"

Comment: @theTinMan got it, will be be careful in future